# Intermolecular forces between carbon dioxide and water

Tags: solubility, intermolecular-forces, hydrogen-bond

I'm wondering which intermolecular forces will exist between carbon dioxide and water. Instinctively, I would expect there to be only dispersion forces between the 2 molecules, because carbon dioxide is non-polar due to its linear shape. However, even though carbon dioxide is non-polar, it still contains dipoles. I'm curious if its possible that these dipoles in carbon dioxide will allow it to form dipole-dipole forces (or even H-bonds) with water. Could the partially negative oxygen atomspotentially accept a H-bond from water, even if carbon dioxide is non-polar?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [this PubChem data table](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/carbon_dioxide#section=Chemical-and-Physical-Properties) for the physical and chemical properties of carbon dioxide, it contains two hydrogen bond sites (each of the oxygens). This largely accounts for the high solubility of $\ce{CO2}$ compared to that of non-hydrogen bonding compounds like methane, which has about $\mathrm{1/25^{th}}$ of the Henry's law solubility in water as does $\ce{CO2}$.